# How to Append XML Childnode right after the last child in PHP

Tags: php, xml

### My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<file>
    <filename>RLR7610_2012090200293-1.csv</filename>
    <filename>RLR7610_2012090200293-1.pdf</filename>
</file>
```

### My PHP Code:

```
function generateXML($_datetodelete, $_filenames){
  $xmlFile = new DOMDocument();      
  $xmlFile->load($this->achive_folder.$_datetodelete.".xml");
  $file = $xmlFile->documentElement;

  foreach($_filenames as $filename) {
    $node_filename = $xmlFile->createElement("filename");
    $node_filename->appendChild($xmlFile->createTextNode($filename));                
    $file->appendData($node_filename);
    $xmlFile->saveXML();
  }
}
```

I want to loop and append child node after last tag `<filename>` with its text but currently it replace all of old tag `<filename>` instead of append. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append new child to your xml file at the end please use below code.

```
<?php
    //Load the scores XML file
    $xmlFile = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlFile -> load('file.xml');
    $files = $xmlFile -> getElementsByTagName('file');
    $newfile = $xmlFile -> createElement("filename", "RLR7610_2012090200293-1.xml");
    $files -> item(0) -> appendChild($newfile);
    $xmlFile -> save('file.xml');

    // View XML File Content
    if (file_exists('file.xml')) 
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
        print_r($xml);
    } else
        exit('Failed to Open');
?>
```